# Jquery check if date is current date or passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am not using the date picker, I have a string that outputs a date the following way:

`<span class="expiry-date">30-Jun-2014</span>` (can't do anything about that, so I have to work with that)

I am checking the current date and output it so that it matches this particular string:

```
 var d = new Date();

var day = d.getDate();

var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];

var month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];


var output = (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '-' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + d.getFullYear();
```

then I am trying to compare the two, to see if the date in "expiry-date" is the current date or already  passed:

```
 var expiryDate = $('.expiry-date').text();

      if ($('.expiration-settings').text() == "1"){

      }else{
    if (output >= expiryDate) {
        $('.event-price, #event-registration').hide();
        $('.expiry-date').text('This event is no longer open for registration');
    } else {
        $('.expiry-date').hide();
    }
           }
```

[Live demo](https://event-booking-test.worldsecuresystems.com/events-1/event-1)

I am doing something wrong, because it only checks the day (numeric, understandable, but I am not sure how to fix this so it actually checks the date and not only a number.)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: I changed the [DEMO](https://event-booking-test.worldsecuresystems.com/events-1/event-1) so its easier to see what I need to do.

Comment: Please bear in mind due to timezone differences you may still get registrations after the date 'has passed'. You can use server time.

Comment: yea, and i think that's my problem, how do I use server time?

Comment: Depending on your technology, you can write a simple script that can be called via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
if ($('.expiration-settings').text() == "1"){

}else{
var date = new Date($(".expiry-date").text().trim()).getTime(),
presentDate = new Date();
presentDate.setHours(0,0,0);
if(date>=presentDate.getTime()) {
$('.event-price, #event-registration').hide();
$('.expiry-date').text('This event is no longer open for registration');
} else {
$('.expiry-date').hide();
}
}
```